# how to call python script in Scala ide

Tags: scala

I want to run python script in Scala program, I ran the python script in spark-shell, but same code I tried in Scala IDE it throws "No such file or directory".

My code in spark-shell:-
python file : a.py

scala script:-

```
file="a.py"

Seq("python",file) !
```

Above code ran successfully in spark-shell and I tried same code in Scala IDE

```
object newtest {

 def runpython(file:String)={

  Seq("python",file) !

}

def main(args: Array[String]):Unit={

val file="/sample/a.py"

runpython(file)

}

}
```

note:- "/sample" is project folder in scala IDE

Please help me on this.

Thanks,
Prasad.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that the missing file is `python`.
try setting the full path of the python executable

Comment: I tried with python executable path but still I am getting same error.../usr/bin/python: can't open file '/sample/a.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: So, does the file `/sample/a.py` exist?